# ADODB query to table in same Excel file is failing

Tags: excel, vba

This excel macro used to work yesterday but today it is throwing an error and I can't figure why:

```
Sub QueryTableTest()
    Dim connection As Object
        
    '--- Connect to the current datasource of the Excel file
    Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With connection
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
    End With
    
    '--- Write the SQL Query. In this case, we are going to select manually the data range
    '--- To print the whole information of the table
    
    TableAddress = Replace(Sheets("Llistat Rebuts").Range("LlistaRebuts").Address, "$", "")
    TableAddress = "[Llistat Rebuts$" & TableAddress & "]"

    
    Sql = "SELECT * FROM " & TableAddress & " where [pendent] <>0"
    '--- Sql = "SELECT * FROM " & TableAddress
    
    '--- Run the SQL query
    Set result = connection.Execute(Sql)
    
    '--- Fetch information
    Do
        ' Print the information of every column of the result
        Debug.Print result("direccion"); ";" & result("pendent")
        
        result.MoveNext
        RecordCount = RecordCount + 1
    Loop Until result.EOF
    
    '--- Print the amount of results
    Debug.Print vbNewLine & RecordCount & " results found."
End Sub
```

The error I am getting when trying to open the ADODB connection is the following:

[image]

Which in spanish means:

> "The Microsoft Access database engine can not open the file " or write
> to it. another user already opened it exclusively or you need
> permissions to read or write data"

I am the only user accessing this file and the macro is simply accessing the already opened file, just as it did yesterday....

Comment: Does `ThisWorkbook.Path` point to a file on disk, or is it an HTTP path?

Comment: @TimWilliams ThisWorkbook.Path is pointing to a file on disk.